# How to move directory into subdirectory in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, relative-path

I finished creating the tree, just need help on how to move sample_dir1 (which is a sub directory of the home directory) into sample_dir using relative pathname. Viewing the tree below will make the question much easier to understand:

```
$
ULI101 Assignment 2.3:  Practice Specifying Path Names                Page 3/15
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sample_dir1
`-- sample_dir
    |-- admin
    |-- cambridge
    |   |-- cafeteria
    |   |-- library
    |   `-- security
    |       |-- annex
    |       |-- building
    |       `-- parking
    |-- faculty
    |-- history.exe
    |-- markham
    |   |-- annex
    |   |-- building1
    |   `-- parking
    |-- oxford
    |   |-- outline.doc
    |   |-- programming
    |   |   `-- report.pdf
    |   `-- security
    `-- stenton
        |-- gen_ed
        `-- lib_arts
            |-- english.txt
            `-- match.doc
```

`sample_dir1` is a subdirectory of your current (home) directory. Move to
`sample_dir` using a relative pathname:

Comment: Your question is unclear. For example, why have you marked this with the `C` tag? Are you coding a solution in C?  Or are you using Linux commands at the shell? Are there specific requirements on how the problem needs to be solved? Please read your question as someone who doesn't know the context of what you have been doing and consider whether it makes any sense to such a person.

Comment: Note that "ASAP" is like painting a downvote target on your back. Don't do it please - readers will answer at their leisure.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mv sample_dir1/ sample_dir/
```

Replace the `sample_dir1/` with the actual location then replace `sample_dir/` with the new location.

Answer (score 1):

try it in local example directory , if you are existing in sample_dir 
then : mv ../sample_dir1 ../sample_dir/
if did not work i am pretty sure i am  not understanding your question or the path names are not clear enough to me